# Want to understand the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

The output of the program is not what I am expecting. Can anyone explain why the continue statement does not direct to printing 90 once again?

```
for num in 23, 45, 50, 65, 76, 90:
    if(num%5!=0):
        continue
    if(num%10==0):
        print(num, end=" ")
        continue
    if(num%3==0):
        print(num, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
45 50 90
```

According to me it should be:

```
45 50 90 90
```

Comment: remove `continue` ?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what `continue` does: it skips the rest of the code and moves the loop to the next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you understand `continue` to mean "continue executing the rest of the loop body". On the contrary, it means "continue with the next value from the loop control sequence." So at the "continue", the loop exits since there is nothing after the `90`. (Otherwise it would simply move on to the next number, so 90 would again not get printed twice.)

Comment: Relevant section from the docs: [break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `continue` and the first `if`:

```
for num in 23, 45, 50, 65, 76, 90:
    if (num%10==0):
        print(num, end=" ")
    if (num%3==0):
        print(num, end=" ")
```

Output:

```
45 50 90 90
```

It doesn't work because `continue` skips the rest of the code and moves to the next element in the loop, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> The continue statement, also borrowed from C, continues with the next iteration of the loop:

Comment: This does not answer the question why the problem happens, or how `continue` works (which would help OP understand why their code behaves the way it does).

Comment: @Lomtrur Can you please un-down-vote now, i fixed it